# Starbound Error

Tags: technical-issues, starbound

I was just trying to launch Starbound and I got this error:
[image: Error]

The launcher then crashes.  I even tried reloading my game and that still didn't help.  I have never gotten this error before.  Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: does the file listed in the 2nd line of the dialog exist? The assets folder is in the Starbound folder, which is with the rest of your Steam games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, unfortunately, is that there might not be anything you can do. Starbound is in early beta, so right now, it is going to have lots of bugs and is rather likely to crash.

What you can do is [go to Starbound's forums to submit a bug report](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/crash-reports-post-em-here.34302/). Hopefully, the devs will address whatever is causing your problem soon.

Answer (score 1):

As mates said, Starbound is in Beta, but sometimes installations are not clean. So you can try to uninstall, and install it again. This sometimes makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following my standard game repair routine for Steam games (of course, try playing after each step ^^")
 1. Restart
 2. computer.
    2. Unsubscribe mods added in last session.
    3. Unsubscribe all mods.
    4. Verify game files intergrity (right mouse click on game > Properties > Local files > Verify integrity of game cache).
    5. Uninstall game and delete all of it's content from My Documents (make saves backup!)
    6. Restart computer and reinstall game.
    7. Check Settings > Device manager for ANY yellow/red ! marks - if found solve driver/hardware issue.
    8. Do CLEAN graphics driver installation.
    9. Restore system to last checkpoint.
    10. Reset/reinstall system.

This WILL solve problems IF it's on your end. If you suspect that it's not, stop at 7 or 8 ;)